# Arcsin domain under differentiation

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

according to my solutions manual, the derivative of:

$$ f(x) = \arcsin \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$$

is

$$f'(x) = \frac{-a}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$$

however, my work on this problem has found this answer to be incomplete:

Knowing that the arcsin() function has domain ($-1 \le x \le 1$), shouldn't the answer be:

$$f'(x) = \frac{-a}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}  ; \quad x \ne 0  ?$$

(Please note the absolute value function $|x|$ on the denominator instead of using only $x$ and that $x = 0$ is not in the domain)

Comment: why you are imposing constraint on $x$, i did not get

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Presumably because the function is not defined at 0 (and neither is its derivative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it should be
$$
f'(x) = \frac{-a}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}  ; \quad \text{for } |x| > a.
$$
The original function is defined at $x=\pm a$ but its tangents are vertical at those points, so the derivative is defined only for $x>a$ or $x<-a$.

Answer (score 4):

The solution manual answer is only correct for positive $x$ at which the function is defined. It is not correct for negative $x$. Your $|x|$ fixes things.

One way of seeing that the solution manual is at least incomplete is to note that $\arcsin(a/x)$ is an odd function. So its derivative must be an even function.